# Permitir acesso a arquivos do S3 sem expor URL da AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-aws

Estou precisando gerar links para download de arquivos que estão armazenados no S3, mas minha empresa não quer expor a URL da AWS.
Nosso sistema é desenvolvido em Java e Spring, até então o sistema recuperava o arquivo necessário e enviava pelo Response, mas os arquivos estão se tornando muito grandes para isso continuar viável.
Estou tentando trabalhar com presignedURL, vi em algum lugar que era possível modificar a url gerada para um subdomínio nosso e utilizar uma configuração de cname apontando para a URL do nosso bucket do S3 .s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/...
Minha equipe e eu usamos essa página como referência:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

De qualquer forma, isso não está funcionando. Ao tentar acessar a URL modificada, a aws retorna um acesso negado.

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Use URLs e/ou cookies assinados, que são temporários e facilitam muito esta tarefa: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html